# Individual "editable datagrid" cells appear read-only; how do I make them actually editable?

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch

I have a Lightswitch screen that is an editable datagrid based on a query filter on a table.  The query filters table results by a date range selectable on the screen command bar.

Whenever I run the application, the data displays properly; however, when I try to edit a cell, it turns white for a brief moment, then goes grey (the control may be disabled - this exact behavior may be inherent to the cosmopolitan shell/theme).  Additionally, the group of add/edit/delete entry buttons are disabled as well.

I've searched for any settings that may be marking these screen elements as read-only, but don't see anything on the individual column level, just the "Use Read-only Controls" at the Data Grid Row level, which is not checked.

I have sa access to the database, and have verified that I can edit the underlying data using SQL Server Management Studio on the same machine as I am running Visual Studio.

Is this a lightswitch configuration issue, a data(base) access problem, or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does your table have a primary key?  Tables without a primary key default to a read-only state.

Comment: Beat me to it.  Yes, that appears to have been the issue.  However, the table I was working with had an implied 3x compound key (stuck with the DB schema, don't get me started...), which Lightswitch recognized correctly on import.

Comment: I ended up using a trigger/stored procedure to export the data I need to a separate table that has a proper primary key and it seems to be working with no issue.  I probably should have realized that sooner, but the key icons on the 3x compound key elements within the IDE kept me thinking that it knew how to properly bind the data back to SQL.  Thanks for the answer!